# Export work on SqlDeveloper but not with Exp Oracle Command

Tags: sql, oracle, export, oracle-sqldeveloper

I can make an export of a table with SQLDeveloper and it works fine. But with Exp command of oracle, I have the following error

```
C:\>exp CHORUS_RO/uiopfdsq@C2PROD TABLES=(USER_CHORUS.CHO_FAQ_ITEM) file='D:\exports'

Export: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Ven. Ao¹t 3 18:30:47 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.


Connected to: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bit
Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, OLAP, Data Mining
and Real Application Testing options
Export done in WE8MSWIN1252 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
server uses AL32UTF8 character set (possible charset conversion)

About to export specified tables via Conventional Path ...
EXP-00009: no privilege to export USER_CHORUS's table CHO_FAQ_ITEM
Export terminated successfully with warnings.
```

Why ? What I can do apart giving privilege to export as I am not abilited to do it ?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the export utility on other schemas without privileges - it's a security issue.

[From the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10701/original_export.htm#BABJIGDI):

> If you do not have the system privileges contained in the
>   EXP_FULL_DATABASE role, then you cannot export objects contained in
>   another user's schema. For example, you cannot export a table in
>   another user's schema, even if you created a synonym for it.

Note also that the use of exp is desupported starting with 11g. It is preferred to use expdp.

A possible workaround is to export the USER_CHORUS's schema by invoking exp as that user.

Comment: In MySQL, you have the ability to backup data even without privileges using --single-transaction option http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-mysqldump-got-error1044-access-denied/. I don't understand Oracle philosophy, so I can read data using SELECT on a table that is not mine but I can't backup this data? WTF?

Comment: If you need the privileges, get the DBA to grant them. If the DBA won't, there's probably a reason.

Comment: I don't see any reason to prevent data backup if you can read it.

Comment: Perhaps it's not really your data to backup.  Just because you can read it doesn't mean it's yours.

Comment: Sure. Personally, if I don't want my data to be backup, I would not give the possibility to read it. Maybe we cannot backup data the easy way using Oracle tools but everybody knows that as long as you have read access, you can hack and copy data.

Comment: To complete my comment, you can copy data using CREATE TABLE new_table AS (SELECT * FROM old_table); (http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/create_table2.php) and then use exp/imp tool to export/import backup since you will own the newly created table. Only table constraints will need to be recreated.